# Create PDF and send mail on scheduled task fails

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, iis-8, pdfsharp

I created a scheduled task that is supposed to scrape data from a website, store this in the database, create a daily pdf and send a weekly mail.

The first 2 parts run smoothly, but it seems that the other 2 are skipped regardless of what I try to do.

Creating a file is not the problem because it creates a daily .log file and writes to it.

For the pdf I use the PdfSharp library, for the mail the System.Net.Mail.

### PDF

```
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
renderer.Document = document;
renderer.RenderDocument();
string directory = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}
string filename = directory + @"\NewCos" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + ".pdf";
if (renderer.PageCount > 0)
    renderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific? Are you able to see your pdf file?

Comment: No, after the database insert has been done, the creation of the file and the sending of the mail are not executed

Comment: I will add a code for pdf creation.

Comment: Oh ... I'm using iTextSharp for pdf creation, if that would help, let me know to send you the code.

Comment: If at the end of the day, it'll work, I wouldn't mind redesigning my program

Comment: Ok cool. I was looking for a good pdf creator, and finally I found this iTextSharp the best.

Comment: I was doubting between those 2 as well but a friend recommended PdfSharp together with MigraDoc

Comment: Where does `document` comes from (and how is it created?). PdfSharp is alright and works just fine. In the code example you have pasted, no mails are send. How are we suppose to guess what the problem is if we don't see the code?

Comment: It's true that in the code I only show the PDF part, but it's my intention on solving this first. I think that the problem is not related to my code but rather to my IIS settings. As commented below on the answer, it's set up with administrator rights

Comment: How about using an absolute path for directory? Your code creates a "2014" directory in the working directory. Did you check the directory is created? I don't see try/catch in your code. Do you get an exception? Since you're able to write log files, logging exceptions might lead to the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It were simply some components that were not installed and the fact that I used relative paths iso fixed direcory settings

Answer (score -1):

first of all add iTextSharp nuget Pack to your project

[itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

then for creating a pdf you just need to do something like this:

```
  Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, -60, -40, 10, 10);
  PdfPTable MainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
  PdfPCell pdfTableCell11 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Hellod PDF!", RegularFont10));
  MainTable.AddCell(pdfTableCell11);
  string path =  "C:\\Customer\\";
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(path + "\\Invoice_" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
  myDocument.Open();
  myDocument.Add(MainTable);
  myDocument.Close();
```

if you have a complex pdf you can manage it by creating tables inside tables ... based on my experience it is better to have a main table with just one cell (which is all your doc) and then create any desire table and add those to this main table. so instead of "PdfPCell" you might have different "PdfPTable"s for each section.

Comment: by the way ... document is basically that instance that is located in iTextSharp.text namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your example. Locally everything works fine and when I publish this to the server, it's exactly the same. It does not create the file

Comment: hmmm, first of all under what user credential is this process running? check writing permission for that user on the location on server.

Comment: Administrator rights with highest privileges. Complete folder and subfolders are not read only